# Color in floating-point texture of HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl

In the HLSL Pixel Shader, the code is as follows:

```
float Exposure_Level;
sampler Environment;
float4 ps_main(float3 dir: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR 
{
   // Read texture and determine HDR color based on alpha
   // channel and exposure level
   float4 color = texCUBE(Environment, dir);
   return color * ((1.0+(color.a*64.0))* Exposure_Level);
}
```

this pass would be rendered to a floating-point texture, which format is A16R16G16B16. But I don't quite understand why the color should be multiplied by

```
((1.0+(color.a*64.0))* Exposure_Level)
```

which could be as large as 65 or larger.

A in color is between 0 to 1, and Exposure_Level should be greater than 0.

If the color is multiplied by a number like this, the result may be very large, and why would that still work?

Comment: Did you read the paper about the theory of HDR rendering? maybe that'd answer your question.

Comment: @rashmatash Thank you for your advicing, where can I read the paper plz?

Comment: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~reinhard/cdrom/tonemap.pdf is the paper. Also look at this article: http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/a-closer-look-at-tone-mapping/ and http://filmicgames.com/archives/75
Some keywords to search are: tone mapping, HDR lighting